# Facing issue in read selected radio button value in google form by using Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am new to Google App script.
I have form with multi choice option. For example i have two option like payment and balance. If i choose payment and click submit button some operation will happen. If i choose balance some other operation will happen. For that i am trying to read the selected option. But i couldn't. Below is the code i have tried to read. Can someone help.

I tried with this. It is giving all form responses. Also this one is giving values while running script. But trying via form it is not working.

```
function myFunctiontest() {
   var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
   var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemr,title,res;
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];    
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j]   
    var item =  itemResponse.getItem();//.asMultipleChoiceItem();
                itemResponse.getItem().getType(),    
                itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
                itemResponse.getResponse();
                res = itemResponse.getResponse().;
    if (item.getType() == 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE' && res == 'A')  
    {
       itemr= itemResponse.getItem().asMultipleChoiceItem(),    
       title =itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
       res =  itemResponse.getResponse();
       Logger.log('Response Type : ',itemr );
       Logger.log('Response Type title  :',title );    
       Logger.log('Response Type  res:',res ); 
    }

     }            
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you saving the responses to a sheet? Try your script "onformsubmit" and catch the field value using parameter(e)

Comment: So you are basically trying to get the responses of that specific multiple choice question instead of the whole form responses, am I right?

Comment: Yes. I want to read specific multi choice question. Based on selected value i need to do some action.

Comment: Hi ! Have you taken a look at [this example of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)? Looking at your code I can tell (similarly to the example) that if you want to retrieve a specific answer of a question of the form (for then apply a conditional on it) you will need to access the specific array index of the response array. **Could you please show what you are getting from the log** (dont include sensitive data) **and in which question are you interested so that I can indicate you how to access it**? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving below a function which I use to send an email (by referring to two other sheets) on receiving a form response.

You have to make a trigger "onFormSubmit" from the app script editer (click the clock icon).

```
function onFormSumbit(e) {
  var emp = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).getValue();
  var lvss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ywKQViIU2k"); // leave applied
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(lvss);
  var lvsht = lvss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var lvlr = lvsht.getLastRow();
  var vA =lvsht.getRange("A:L").getValues();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  html+='<tr>';
  for(var i=0;i< 12 ;i++) {//make title
       html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',vA[0][i]);
     }
  html+='</tr>';
  for (i=1;i<lvlr;i++){
    if (vA[i][1]==emp){
      html+='<tr>';
      for (j=0;j<12;j++) {
         if (j==0 || j==2 ){
            vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatDate(vA[i][j],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
          }//if date
         if ( j==4 && vA[i][j] !=="" ){
            vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatDate(vA[i][j],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
          }//if date
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',vA[i][j]);
      }//for emp
      html+='</tr>';
    }//if
  }//for
  html+='</table><br>';
  var empss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_87o"); // emp master 
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(empss);
  var empsht = empss.getSheetByName("Emp");
  var emplr = empsht.getLastRow();
  var empvals =empsht.getRange("A:H").getValues();
  for (i=1;i<emplr;i++){
    if (empvals[i][0]==emp){
      var em1=empvals[i][7];
      var name=empvals[i][1]
      break;
    }//if
  }//for
  var subject="Your Online Leave History of "+name;
  if (em1=="") {} else {
  //MailApp.sendEmail(em1, subject, html);}
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: em1,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: html
    });
  }
}
//
//
```

Comment: I am looking for google form not for Spreadsheet. I have used the below code.But it is returning all the responses instead of current response. I want to read current value.

Comment: Kindly help me on getting current form values.